¿Como arreglar el estilo de las cabeceras de DataTables.js dentro de un Card de Bootstrap 5?
Tengo un formulario en C# ASP.NET y uso el plugin datatables.js el cual se encuentra en la siguiente liga:
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
En paginas normales se muestra bien las tablas, pero dentro de controles Card de Bootstrap 5 las cabeceras se ven así:


Agregar un [MCVE] a la pregunta
